# How can I take the lines of a textarea and put them in a left and right aligned set of elements split on ":" for each row?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text area and I want to align right the text after every ':'
e.g:

```
Name:                                       Pepito
Lastname:                                    Perez
Id:                                      123456789
qwertyuuiopadsadfsafssffas:                      0
```

Is there a way to do it with css?
Another option is with Js, but I can't find a good strategy to solve the problem. I think than something similar to this might work.

```
$($("textarea")[0]).text().replace(/[^:]/g, "something here")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it have to be a `textarea`? That seems odd, as opposed to some other kind of block-level element. `textarea` is for **input**.

Comment: Yes it needs to be a textarea or at least I need to take the content directly from the textarea and paste it in something else that looks like a textarea

Comment: I would rephrase this as: "How can I take the lines of a textarea and put them in a left and right aligned set of elements split on ":" for each row?"  Attempting to do this with a textarea would mean inserting spaces between and you will have a great deal of challenges with kerning and font dependency making this near impossible to accomplish as stated.

Comment: Ty Mark, that is a better description of my question

Comment: @Sergio - Ah hah! That means it doesn't need to be a `textarea`, and yes, you can use CSS for this. I'll leave it to someone else to show how to do that, as I've already done the `textarea` version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with CSS with a `textarea`, no. The JavaScript way is fairly simple, but it seems odd to do this to with a `textarea`, as they're for **input**.

Still:

```js
const WIDTH = 50;

function format(ta) {
    ta.val(
        // Get the value
        ta.val()
        // Split into lines, then map each line
        .split(/[\r\n]+/).map(line => {
            // Split into left and right parts
            const match = /^\s*([^:]*:)\s*(.*)$/.exec(line);
            if (!match) {
                return line;
            }
            const [, left, right] = match;
            // Insert padding up to WIDTH
            const padding = " ".repeat(WIDTH - left.length - right.length);
            return left + padding + right;
        })
        // Join back into one string
        .join("\n")
    );
}

setTimeout(() => format($("#the-textarea")), 800);
```

```html
<textarea rows="6" cols="50" id="the-textarea">Name: Pepito
Lastname: Perez
Id: 123456789
qwertyuuiopadsadfsafssffas: 0</textarea>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As good as it will get, but still super odd request :)  We agree on that.

Comment: To illustrate my font and kerning comment on the question, use this CSS here: `#the-textarea  { font-family: "New Century Schoolbook", serif }`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I understand than my question maybe is a little bit weird. The thing is that I can't change the code and only can create changes in one css file and one js file

Comment: @Sergio - :-) Fair enough. Glad that helped!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It did. Ty!